# Using http.request to request data but got a heart-shaped icon?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

Code:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      var raw_data = chunk
      **console.log('raw_data:', raw_data);**
  }
});
```

This is what I got (can't copy & paste here so I put a screen shot)

[Output when I print the chunk http://www.awflasher.com/temp_output.png](http://www.awflasher.com/temp_output.png)

Comment: can't see the screenshot.

Comment: @gnanz I've changed a host. I don't know why the default hosting doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving binary data.

When you log the data out you are interpreting this as text, sending it through an encoding process.  My best guess is that the heart symbol is the first byte, then you have a sequence that terminates the string.

Use a simple loop to write out the data if you want to visualize it.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. Yes, I think it's very possible. But how do I just want to get the whole HTML plain content without using external libraries?